# Prove a set is numerable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have 4 different sets:

a) $\{ [x]: x \in \mathbb{R}\}$

b) $\mathbb Q \cup (2,+\infty)$

c) $\{n^2: n \in \mathbb N\}$

d) $\mathbb Q \cap (2,+\infty)$

A set is numerable if exists a bijective function from $\mathbb N$ to $A$

the c) is numerable because exists $f:\mathbb N \rightarrow A$ so that $f(n)=n^2$

but in the other cases?

Comment: @Peter isn’t a) using the Gauss-bracket (ie rounding) and not the absolute value? In this case I think the set *is* enumerable, since it reduces to the set of integers $\Bbb$, which is enumerable.

Comment: Oops, I read it as an absolute value. So, $a)$ is enumerable as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a)$ is numerable because the set is identical with $\mathbb Z$

$b)$ is not numerable : Already the interval $(2,3)$ is uncountable.

$d)$ is numerable because it is an infinite subset of $\mathbb Q$